# Problems with Loading lazy

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to apply lazy loading to the images on my website when I apply it on a static image through a URL or assets, this attribute works perfectly

But, when I get images from my database and apply this attribute to it, for some reason, it doesn't work

Example of static image that does work

```
<img loading="lazy"  src="{{asset('img/minus.png')}}"/>
```

Example with dynamic images from my database that DOES NOT work

```
@foreach($product_all->product_images as $product_image_all)
    <img loading="lazy" id="image-{{$product_all->id}}" src="{{url('product/'.$product_image_all->image)}}">
@endforeach
```

My method to get the images from the database

```
public function getImage($filename) {
    $file = \Storage::disk('products')->get($filename);

    return new Response($file, 200);
}
```

Where is the fault? Why can't I get it to work?

Comment: Would `id="image-{{$product_all->id}}"` not generate the same id for every image?

Comment: No, because each image only belongs to one product and I have it limited so that despite the existence of more images per product, it only shows one.

Also, if I remove the id it still doesn't work ...

Comment: That looks like a typo, but each iteration should be `id="image-{{$product_image_all->id}}"` to assign the correct/unique element id.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was that I had to also put loading = "lazy" to the images that I was loading above because some were repeated